# 301 redirect, redundant index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, http-status-code-301

I have one problem. I want to redirect my website address from www.lapnet.net.pl to lapnet.net.pl via 301 redirect in htaccess. Always when I try to use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lapnet.net.pl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lapnet.net.pl$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Browser redirecting me to http://lapnet.net.pl/index.php?view=
(view is variable responsible for loading content). How can I avoid this "index.php?view="?
Thanks for help

Comment: Probably, you have rewrites in `.htaccess` files in upper folders

Comment: I think you are asking for the rewrite rule to do something like this:  `http://site.com/index.php?view=1 => http://site.com/view/1`. If so please reword your question.

Comment: There is nothing in this rule that would *add* `/index.php?view=`, so either there is another rewrite rule taking effect, or there is something in your code that is doing another redirect.

Comment: complete htaccess:
http://pastebin.com/G5RjxvzD

Answer (score 0):

The last line looks suspicious to me: I would add a `/` after the domain and add the query string but I'm not sure if that is the cause of your problem:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lapnet.net.pl/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
                                                    ^^^ add original query string
                                       ^ slash here
```